# How to use typedef NS_ENUM properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, typedef

I want to use typedef NS_ENUM to create a switch method in my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method to create actions for different types of cell selection.

So I saw some apple sample code that helped me to understand more or less how this should be done, and from some reason its not working.

This is my relevant methods in the view controller:

```
#import "SettingsTableViewController.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

// Corresponds to the section index of the table view
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, SettingsControllerSection) {
    SettingsControllerSectionCell = 0,
    OtherControllerSection
};

// Corresponds to the row in the first section.
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, SettingsControllerWebsitesSection) {
    FirstWebsiteController = 0,
    SecondWebsiteController,
    ThirdWebsiteController,
    FourthWebsiteController,
    FithWebsiteController,
    SixthWebsiteController,
    SeventhWebsiteController
};

// Corresponds to the row in the second section.
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, SettingsControllerOtherSection) {
    RateUsController = 0,
    ContactUsControllerRow
};


@interface SettingsTableViewController ()<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation SettingsTableViewController

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    //Settings up the sections title
    if(section == 0) {

        return @"News Sources";
    } else {
        return @"Share & Care";
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    //getting the cell value
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSString *cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
    //adding switch objects to the news sources section
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        UISwitch *switchview = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        //switchview.thumbTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:14.0/255.0 green:118.0/255.0 blue:127.0/255.0 alpha:1];
        [switchview setOnTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:14.0/255.0 green:118.0/255.0 blue:127.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
        cell.accessoryView = switchview;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)sendEmail {
    // Email Subject
    NSString *emailTitle = @"Test Email";
    // Email Content
    NSString *messageBody = @"iOS programming is so fun!";
    // To address
    NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"support@appcoda.com"];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
    [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

    // Present mail view controller on screen
    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Close the Mail Interface
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    SettingsControllerSection section = indexPath.section;

    if (OtherControllerSection == section) {
        SettingsControllerOtherSection row = indexPath.row;

        switch (row) {

            case RateUsController:
                NSLog(@"rate us was pressed");
                break;

            case ContactUsControllerRow:
                [self sendEmail];
                NSLog(@"send email was pressed");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I see that also my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not getting called....why is that?

Thanks!!

Comment: If `didSelect` isn't even getting called then this question is not about NS_ENUM.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the tableview's delegate.

tableView.delegate = self;

Make sure your tableview's delegate has been valued.

Then, how many sections ?

The NS_ENUM is just another declare of enum.

Comment: I have set the delegate self.tableView.delegate = self;, it didn't work..:/

Comment: Do the cells highlight?

Comment: no its not highlight...and I don't think the table view delegate had been valued..

Comment: make sure you're tableview is not nil when you set the delegate, you should set the deleate after tableview had been valued. generally in the viewcontroller's method viewDidLoad